# How to sync a Salesforce Object with Postgres using Heroku Connect

Tags: heroku, sync, heroku-connect

I want to use Heroku Connect to sync a postgres database (an app deployed on heroku and having a postgres DB) with a Salesforce schema.

When I start a new mapping on heroku connect, I have all Salesforce Objects, I can choose objects I want to sync. But I do not see my postgres fields.

Ex : how to ask Heroku connect to sync my salesforce Name__c with my field Name (thas comes from postgres) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a Postgres DB to Heroku Connect and configure mapping(s), HC will create schema (tables) in Postgres.  You could pre-create tables in Postgres if you really know what you're doing but this is not recommended. You cannot bring your own, pre-existing Postgres schema and map it to Salesforce...unless it looks exactly like Salesforce schema. If the latter is true, see pre-create warning above.

Please go through the Trailhead [HC tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-heroku-connect) and take a look at the [HC docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-database-tables) for more info.